# How to write a regex in a single line

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this code:

```
str = 'printf("My name is %s and age is %0.2d", name, age);'

SPECIFIERS = 'diuXxofeEgsc'
format_specifiers  = /((?:%(?:\*?([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)*(?:[#{SPECIFIERS}]))))/i

variables = /([.[^"]]*)\);$/

format = str.scan(format_specifiers)
var = str.scan(variables).first.first.split(/,/)
```

Is there any way a single regex can do that in a couple of lines?

My desired output is:

```
%s,  name
%0.2d,  age
```

Comment: What do you think `/([.[^"]]*)\);$/` means in regex-ese?

Comment: It means start from the end of the line and take everything unless it found `"` so after scan it will return `, name, age`, mean it will give all the variables or even equations (like `a+b`) so i can map them to their required format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big believer in keeping regular expressions as simple as possible; They can too quickly mushroom into unwieldy/unmaintainable messes. I'd start with something like this, then tweak as necessary:

```
str = 'printf("My name is %s and age is %0.2d", name, age);'

formats = str.scan(/%[a-z0-9.]+/) # => ["%s", "%0.2d"]

str[/,(.+)\);$/] # => ", name, age);"
vars = str[/,(.+)\);$/].scan(/[a-z]+/) # => ["name", "age"]

puts formats.zip(vars).map{ |a| a.join(', ')}

# >> %s, name
# >> %0.2d, age
```

Comment: ▲ I second what you said about RegEx and also your solution. Could you check my [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/lY1kY2/1) ? I am almost there using RegEx. **This might be against your belief though.**

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two parts:

- Q1: Is it possible to do this with a single regex?
- Q2: Can this be done in one or two lines of code?

The answer to both questions is "yes".

```
format_specifiers = /
                    %[^\s\"\z]+  # match % followed by > 0 characters other than a
                                 # whitespace, a double-quote or the end of the string
                    /x           # free-spacing regex definition mode

variables         = /
                    ,\s*         # match comma followed by >= 0 whitespaces 
                    \K           # forget matches so far
                    [a-z]        # match a lowercase letter
                    \w*          # match >= 0 word characters
                    /x
```

You can decide, after testing, if these two regexes do their jobs adequately. For testing, refer to [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

```
 r = /
     (?:#{format_specifiers})    # match format_specifiers in a non-capture group
     |                           # or
     (?:#{variables})            # match variables in a non-capture group
     /x

     #=> /
         (?:(?x-mi:
           %[^\s\"\z]+ # match % followed by > 0 characters other than a
                       # whitespace, a double-quote or the end of the string
           ))          # match format_specifiers in a non-capture group
         |             # or
         (?:(?x-mi:
           ,\s*        # match comma followed by >= 0 whitespaces 
           \K          # forget matches so far
           [a-zA-Z]    # match a letter
           \w*         # match >= 0 word characters
         ))            # match variables in a non-capture group
         /x
```

`r` can of course also be written:

```
/(?:(?x-mi:%[^\s\"\z]+))|(?:(?x-mi:,\s*\K[a-zA-Z]\w*))/
```

One advantage of constructing `r` from two regexes is that each of the latter can be tested separately.

```
str = 'printf("My name is %s and age is %0.2d", name, age);'

arr = str.scan(r)
  #=> ["%s", "%0.2d", "name", "age"] 
arr.each_slice(arr.size/2).to_a.transpose.map { |s| s.join(',  ') }
  #=> ["%s,  name", "%0.2d,  age"]
```

I have five lines of code. We could reduce this to two by simply substituting out `r` in `str.scan(r)`. We could make it a single line by writing:

```
str.scan(r).tap { |a|
  a.replace(a.each_slice(a.size/2).to_a.transpose.map { |s| s.join(',  ') }) }
  #=> ["%s,  name", "%0.2d,  age"]
```

with `r` substituted out.

The steps here are as follows:

```
a = str.scan(r)
  #=> ["%s", "%0.2d", "name", "age"] 
b = a.each_slice(a.size/2)
  #=> a.each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["%s", "%0.2d", "name", "age"]:each_slice(2)> 
c = b.to_a
  #=> [["%s", "%0.2d"], ["name", "age"]] 
d = c.transpose
  #=> [["%s", "name"], ["%0.2d", "age"]] 
e = d.map { |s| s.join(',  ') }
  #=> ["%s,  name", "%0.2d,  age"] 
a.replace(e)
  #=> ["%s,  name", "%0.2d,  age"]
```

The methods used (aside from `Array#size`) are [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan), [Enumerable#each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), [Enumerable#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a), [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) and [Array#replace](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-replace).